# Changes to PHP script aren't executed

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-hosting

I'm building a website with a very basic blog-like "News" functionality. Basically, you enter the title, author, author's picture, date, and message of the news update to on a password-protected form, and then the magic of PHP grabs that stuff and sticks it in a MySQL database. Then, using more PHP, these little articles are dynamically loaded on a "News" page. The script that uploads the data to the MySQL database works fine. So does the script that displays the news on the webpage. Here's the problem: if I edit the "display" PHP script and upload the edited script onto the hosting server, those edits aren't reflected in the website. Here's my code:

```
<?php

include('dbconnect.php'); //connects to database

//select the table
$result = mysql_query("select * from newscms order by id desc limit 5");

//grab all the content from the table
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $r['id'];
    $title = $r['title'];
    $date = $r['date'];
    $user = $r['user'];
    $icon = $r['icon'];
    $message = $r['message'];

    //displays the rows
    echo "<img src='$icon' align='left'/><strong>$title</strong> <br/> 
    Posted on $date 
    Posted by: <strong>$user</strong><br />
    $message <br />";
} 

?>
```

Now if I changed the "echo" function to instead show something like:

```
 echo "<img src='$icon' align='right' width='12' height='24'/><em>$title</em> <br/> 
    Posted on $date 
    Posted by: <strong>$user</strong><br />
    $message <br /> I like turtles";
```

(Notice I have changed the alignment and size of the icon, changed `<strong>` to `<em>` for the title, and added the text "I like turtles" to the end)

with all these changes, **absolutely nothing changes on the webpage!**

Why? It's driving me insane! Is there some flaw in my script I can't see? Is it a server-side problem that I should contact my web host about? (And before you ask, yes, I cleared my browser cache.) Help please!

Comment: did you make sure you're editing the right script? made your edits elsewhere and failed to upload the new version? uploaded to the wrong place?

Comment: also, are you uploading it to the right place? In some hosts, switching ftp users can leave an abandoned directory that can look like the web directory.

Comment: Also, you forgot your semicolon after you echo statement.  But I'm in agreement with @MarcB that it just seems to be an uploading issue.  Have you tried to download the working version from your ftp server to see if the changes are reflected?

Comment: Almost 99% of the time, this happens to me when I'm editing a file where I shouldn't be. +1 for wrong path.

Comment: Are you running APC (or other opcode caching) on your server?

Comment: I've been using Filezilla this whole time and haven't changed users. I can easily change html and css files and changes are reflected right away (I just did, in fact). And yes, when I download the file from the server, it is the same as the file I uploaded.

Comment: @MarkBaker I think the server uses ZendOptimizer? But if that were the issue, would the website still display completely new MySQL entries in the form of new News articles right away?

Comment: ZendOptimizer wouldn't affect the data values retrieved from the database in any way, just the php code that you ran: it isn't a data cache

Comment: @MarkBaker So how would I disable it?

Comment: Restarting the webserver is one option: that flushes the cache; but there should also be a development setting to check for newer versions of script files and reload if there is an updated script (that will probably be a php.ini setting, requiring a webserver restart anyway)

Comment: I just figured it out, and oh god I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.
It was a pathname problem. Sort of.
At first, I was implementing the display functionality by using a PHP include function to include a "display.php" file. Then, for reasons now forgotten, I commented out that function and instead copy-pasted the contents of the display.php file into the webpage file. Of course, I forgot that I did that, and have been editing the display.php file. Solution: stop being an idiot, uncomment that include, and delete the rest. All fixed. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 create a new folder to your desktop called any name then download the updated file from your ftp folder to your local folder . then open that file you  downloaded and see if really those changes you made exists . from there you might be able to trace what might be the cause of that problem . Also if I were you I would have deleted the that file in the ftp and I upload the current one so that I can be sure.

Comment: Thanks but nope :( I've eliminated it being a pathname issue.